# Linux error while loading shared libraries: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, file-not-found, xenomai

Program is part of the Xenomai test suite, cross-compiled from Linux PC into Linux+Xenomai ARM toolchain.

```
# echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH                                                                                                                                          
/lib                                                                                                                                                             
# ls /lib                                                                                                                                                        
ld-2.3.3.so         libdl-2.3.3.so      libpthread-0.10.so                                                                                                       
ld-linux.so.2       libdl.so.2          libpthread.so.0                                                                                                          
libc-2.3.3.so       libgcc_s.so         libpthread_rt.so                                                                                                         
libc.so.6           libgcc_s.so.1       libstdc++.so.6                                                                                                           
libcrypt-2.3.3.so   libm-2.3.3.so       libstdc++.so.6.0.9                                                                                                       
libcrypt.so.1       libm.so.6                                                                                                                                    
# ./clocktest                                                                                                                                                    
./clocktest: error while loading shared libraries: libpthread_rt.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Is the `.1` at the end part of the filename? What does that mean anyway?

Comment: This might happen if you have recently installed a shared library and didn't run ldconfig(8) afterwards. Do 'ldconfig', there's no harm in it.

Comment: +1 to @AbiusX comment - running sudo ldconfig (assuming that libraries are in fact where they should be [/usr/bin/lib/, /usr/bin/include/, /usr/local/lib/ and /usr/local/include/ AFAIK], please correct me if I'm wrong) can resolve that problem. Cheers!

Comment: Note that this error can also arise if the permissions on your lib file got changed somehow. Changing the permissions back to 644 solved it for me.

Comment: @AbiusX I ran sudo ldconfig after compiling my program and it worked. Thanks! (The libraries were in /usr/local/lib.)

Comment: we need an update for this. its posted in 2009 for god sake its still happening

Comment: came here with the same problem. hmmm as far as I know I don't have .so.1 files. But I have the lib with .so

Comment: @greendino It's driving me NUTS

Comment: what "update" do you need? there's three good answers to it, some of which may be applicable depending on your specific issue.

Answer (score 579):

Your library is a dynamic library.
You need to tell the operating system where it can locate it at runtime.

To do so,
we will need to do those easy steps:

1. Find where the library is placed if you don't know it.

   ```bash
   sudo find / -name the_name_of_the_file.so
   ```
2. Check for the existence of the dynamic library path environment variable(`LD_LIBRARY_PATH`)

   ```bash
   echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
   ```

   If there is nothing to be displayed, add a default path value (or not if you wish to)

   ```bash
   LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
   ```
3. We add the desired path, export it and try the application.

   Note that the path should be the directory where the `path.so.something` is. So if `path.so.something` is in `/my_library/path.so.something`, it should be:

   ```bash
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/my_library/
   ```

[Reference to source](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/usage.html#shared-libraries)

Comment: The above mentioned answer was very clear, Thanks you first of all. I tried doing this in my Eclipse CDT Project Path (Lubuntu).
/Debug$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/home/akhil/HDE/x86.linux/lib:/home/akhil/HDE/x86.linux/lib..      

                                     
"/home/akhil/HDE/x86.linux/lib" this is where my libraries are actually available even, but still I get the same error. Any suggestions!

Comment: Try a "ldconfig" command after exporting your library.
You might need to execute this command as "sudo".

Comment: I believe `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` should point to the directory containing `path.so.something`, not to `path.so.something` itself.

Comment: This is the right solution for the systems where `sudo ldconfig` cannot be executed, e.g. supercomputers.

Comment: The `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH` command is essential so that other programs can read the environment variable. Without it only the shell can see the variable.

Comment: if you put the export command in a .sh file and you find that it LD_LIBRARY_PATH is not set after the .sh completes, run it as follows:

. ./abc.sh

(There's a dot at the beginning of that line)

Comment: Read: http://xahlee.info/UnixResource_dir/_/ldpath.html <- or google Why LD_LIBRARY_PATH is (evil|bad). It does have it's purpose.

Comment: When `find / -name the_name_of_the_file.so` doesn't yield any results, you can try `sudo find / -iname *the_name_of_the_file*.so*` as [described in this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28460293/4575793)

Comment: @fbicknel that link does say that sometimes you are _forced_ to use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`  even if it’s not something it was designed for.

Comment: For anyone this might help: I had this error in a docker container figuring it'd be same as a regular linux box, but abandoned that approach for this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59859826/9587457

Answer (score 252):

Here are a few solutions you can try:

### ldconfig

As AbiusX pointed out: If you have just now installed the library, you may simply need to run [ldconfig](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ldconfig).

```
sudo ldconfig
```

> ldconfig creates the necessary links and cache to the most recent
>   shared libraries found in the directories specified on the command
>   line, in the file /etc/ld.so.conf, and in the trusted directories
>   (/lib and /usr/lib).

Usually your package manager will take care of this when you install a new library, but not always, and it won't hurt to run ldconfig even if that is not your issue.

### Dev package or wrong version

If that doesn't work, I would also check out [Paul's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/480786/22781) and look for a "-dev" version of the library. Many libraries are split into dev and non-dev packages. You can use this command to look for it:

```
apt-cache search <libraryname>
```

This can also help if you simply have the wrong version of the library installed. Some libraries are published in different versions simultaneously, for example, Python.

### Library location

If you are sure that the right package is installed, and ldconfig didn't find it, it may just be in a nonstandard directory. By default, ldconfig looks in `/lib`, `/usr/lib`, and directories listed in `/etc/ld.so.conf` and `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. If your library is somewhere else, you can either add the directory on its own line in `/etc/ld.so.conf`, append the library's path to `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, or move the library into `/usr/lib`. Then run `ldconfig`.

To find out where the library is, try this:

```
sudo find / -iname *libraryname*.so*
```

(Replace `libraryname` with the name of your library)

If you go the `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` route, you'll want to put that into your `~/.bashrc` file so it will run every time you log in:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/path/to/library
```

Comment: By default, /lib and /usr/lib but not /usr/local/lib?  That has thrown me off several times over my career and wasted hours.

Comment: Adding `.conf` files of my own with the non-standard lib paths I need to `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` (pointed to by `/etc/ld.so.conf`) did the trick.

Comment: +1 for needing to run ldconfig. I wasn't using a package manager. I had to compile from source, so this was necessary.

Comment: Just like @CivFan, I added my own .conf in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d`. After which I (obviously) had to run ldconfig and it worked. I can feel you @DarenW. Its a pain in the butt

Comment: For anybody concerned: [`find -iname ...` is the same as `-name`, but case insensitive. But be wary: it is not part of the standard, so could be absent in the implementation you use.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/230954/318461)

Comment: It's always a good idea to try `sudo ldconfig` first, since you will get the same error if the `.so` isn't in the `ld` cache `/etc/ld.so.cache`, even the `.so` file is in a directory listed in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: In my case I had to [run ldconfig explicitly with path](https://askubuntu.com/a/302900/217506) for it to pick up the libraries there.

Answer (score 151):

**Update**
While what I write below is true as a general answer about shared libraries, I think the most frequent cause of these sorts of message is because you've installed a package, but not installed the `-dev` version of that package.

---

Well, it's not lying - there is no `libpthread_rt.so.1` in that listing.  You probably need to re-configure and re-build it so that it depends on the library you have, or install whatever provides `libpthread_rt.so.1`.

Generally, the numbers after the .so are version numbers, and you'll often find that they are symlinks to each other, so if you have version 1.1 of libfoo.so, you'll have a real file libfoo.so.1.0, and symlinks foo.so and foo.so.1 pointing to the libfoo.so.1.0.  And if you install version 1.1 without removing the other one, you'll have a libfoo.so.1.1, and libfoo.so.1 and libfoo.so will now point to the new one, but any code that requires that exact version can use the libfoo.so.1.0 file.  Code that just relies on the version 1 API, but doesn't care if it's 1.0 or 1.1 will specify libfoo.so.1.  As [orip](https://stackoverflow.com/users/37020/orip) pointed out in the comments, this is explained well [here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html).

In your case, you *might* get away with symlinking `libpthread_rt.so.1` to `libpthread_rt.so`.  No guarantees that it won't break your code and eat your TV dinners, though.

Comment: ... oh god, the .1 is part of the filename. Any idea what does it mean?

Comment: @zaratustra it means version

Answer (score 51):

You need to ensure that you specify the library path during
linking when you compile your .c file:

```
gcc -I/usr/local/include xxx.c -o xxx -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-R/usr/local/lib
```

The `-Wl,-R` part tells the resulting binary to also look for the library
in `/usr/local/lib` at runtime before trying to use the one in `/usr/lib/`.

Comment: This is the option I was looking for.  Perhaps better would be `-Wl,-rpath DIR`.

Comment: This is the personal turning point in my programming-enthusiast life. It's awesome. Thank you!

Comment: This is excatly what I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 33):

Try adding `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, which indicates search paths, to your `~/.bashrc` file

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/path_to_your_library
```

It works!

Comment: After that, the following line should be added to the .bashrc

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Answer (score 13):

The [linux.org reference page](https://www.linux.org/threads/linux-reference-page.8216/) explains the mechanics, but doesn't explain any of the motivation behind it :-(

For that, see [Sun Linker and Libraries Guide](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19253-01/817-1984/)

In addition, note that "external versioning" is largely obsolete on Linux, because symbol versioning (a GNU extension) allows you to have multiple incompatible versions of the same function to be present in a single library. This extension allowed glibc to have the same external version: `libc.so.6` for the last 10 years.

Answer (score 8):

```
cd /home/<user_name>/
sudo vi .bash_profile
```

add these lines at the end

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:<any other paths you want>
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Answer (score 7):

Wanted to add, if your libraries are in a non standard path, run `ldconfig` followed by the path.

For instance I had to run:

```
sudo ldconfig /opt/intel/oneapi/mkl/2021.2.0/lib/intel64
```

to make R compile against Intel MKL

Comment: `sudo ldconfig <PACKAGE>` worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Another possible solution depending on your situation.

If you know that libpthread_rt.so.1 is the same as libpthread_rt.so then you can create a symlink by:

```
ln -s /lib/libpthread_rt.so /lib/libpthread_rt.so.1
```

Then `ls -l /lib` should now show the symlink and what it points to.

Comment: Could this be done for different version? In my case, I have libnsl.so.2, but my command is looking for libnsl.so.1.

Comment: To add to this answer, you can see which directories the linker is looking for the libraries in with `ld --verbose | grep SEARCH_DIR` and check for such near-matches. In my case, I had a problem where I had a `libgcr-4.so.4.0.0` in `/usr/lib` but no `libgcr-4.so.4`, so all I had to do was create a symlink like this answer says and it fixed it.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar error and it didn't fix with giving LD_LIBRARY_PATH in ~/.bashrc .
What solved my issue is by adding .conf file and loading it.
Go to terminal an be in su.

```
gedit /etc/ld.so.conf.d/myapp.conf
```

Add your library path in this file and save.(eg: /usr/local/lib).
You must run the following command to activate path:

```
ldconfig
```

Verify Your New Library Path:

```
ldconfig -v | less
```

If this shows your library files, then you are good to go.

Answer (score 4):

I had this error when running my application with Eclipse CDT on Linux x86.
To fix this:

1. In Eclipse:

   > Run as -> Run configurations -> Environment
2. Set the path

   ```
   LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/my_lib_directory_path
   ```

Answer (score 3):

If you are running your application on Microsoft Windows, the path to dynamic libraries (`.dll`) need to be defined in the `PATH` environment variable.

If you are running your application on UNIX, the path to your dynamic libraries (`.so`) need to be defined in the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 2):

Try to install *lib32z1*:

`sudo apt-get install lib32z1`

Answer (score 2):

I use Ubuntu 18.04

Installing the corresponding `-dev` package worked for me,

```
sudo apt install libgconf2-dev
```

Before installing the above package, I was getting the below error:

```
turtl: error while loading shared libraries: libgconf-2.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

All I had to do was run:

```
sudo apt-get install libfontconfig1
```

I was in the folder located at `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs as the system cannot refer to the library file mentioned. Take the following steps:

1. Running `locate libpthread_rt.so.1` will list the path of all the files with that name. Let's suppose a path is `/home/user/loc`.
2. Copy the path and run `cd home/USERNAME`. Replace USERNAME with the name of the current active user with which you want to run the file.
3. Run `vi .bash_profile` and at the end of the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` parameter, just before `.`, add the line `/lib://home/usr/loc:.`. Save the file.
4. Close terminal and restart the application. It should run.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error and I think its the same reason of yours

> error while loading shared libraries: libnw.so: cannot open shared
>   object  file: No such file or directory

Try this. Fix permissions on files:

```
cd /opt/Popcorn (or wherever it is) 
chmod -R 555 * (755 if not ok)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error and I think its the same reason of yours

```
error while loading shared libraries: libnw.so: cannot open shared object 
file: No such file or directory
```

Try this. **Fix permissions** on files:

```
sudo su
cd /opt/Popcorn (or wherever it is) 
chmod -R 555 * (755 if not ok) 
chown -R root:root *
```

Answer (score 0):

A similar problem can be found  [here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1456202).
I've tried the mentioned solution and it actually works.

The solutions in the previous questions may work. But the following is an easy way to fix it.
It works by reinstalling the package `libwbclient`
in fedora:

```
dnf reinstall libwbclient
```