# iphone dylibs and frameworks are already in the device?

Tags: iphone, entity-framework, dylib

Are dylibs and frameworks already in an iPhone, or does my app actually incorporate them?

Also, in Xcode I see dylibs with identical names. Sometimes the subsequent names are incremented, as in libz.dylib, libz.1.dylib, libz.1.1.3.dylib, and libz.1.2.3.dylib.

If I have to include libz, should I use the one with the highest rev number, assuming that that's what that is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just link to `libz`.

Don't link to a specific version unless it's an absolute requirement, because when the library is updated, the `libz` could be re-linked to the updated version, but the old specific version may be gone. For detail see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480764/linux-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-su/480786#480786) (for Linux, but applies to Darwin too).