# Error loading shared libraries

Tags: shared-libraries, shared

I'm running eclipse on Ubuntu using a g++ compiler and I'm trying to run a sample program that utilizes xerces.

The build produced no errors however, when i attempted to run the program, I would receive this error:

> `error while loading shared libraries: libxerces-c-3.1.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

`libxerces-c-3.1.so` is in the directory `/opt/lib` which I have included as a library in eclipse. The file is there when I checked the folder. When I perform an `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `/opt/lib` is also listed.

Any ideas into where the problem lies? Thanks.

An `ldd libxerces-c-3.1.so` command yields the following output:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffeafff000)
libnsl.so.1 => /lib/libnsl.so.1 (0x00007fa3d2b83000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fa3d2966000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fa3d265f000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007fa3d23dc000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007fa3d2059000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fa3d1e42000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fa3d337d000)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linux error while loading shared libraries: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480764/linux-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-s)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I copied all the library files from /opt/lib into /usr/lib and the program works now. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 33):

Try running `ldconfig` as root to see if it solves the problem.

Comment: I tried running `sudo ldconfig` but it still doesn't work

Comment: Of course it didn't @Nubcake. Do this `echo /opt/lib > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/my-bonus-library-path.conf` or suitable equivalent for your case, as root. Then `ldconfig`. [`ld.so`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html) needs to know where to look for libraries; and it uses a cache, ldconfig rebuilds that cache.

Answer (score 4):

Run `ldd libxerces-c-3.1.so` and examine the output to see if all dependencies can be found.

Comment: I've edited the topic with the result from an ldd command. I'm fairly new to linux so I'm not quite sure what the output means. How do I know if I have all the shared libraries required? Are those the ones listed with the arrows?

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways to do this, most already mentioned here. BUT you want to **avoid accidentally copying your library files into/over those of the system**. This is easily done since people have little imagination in making original unique names for their libraries.

So there are a couple of things to think about:

- Do you need these files to be a permanent part of your system?
- Do you only need to install for testing and frequent updates?
- Do you only need them for running *that* particular command once or twice?
- Where are your native libraries located?

To find your various library locations on your system (apart from using find), look here:

```
cat /etc/ld.so.conf    
cat /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*
```

On Linux there are some standard places:

```
/lib            # for base system (don't use this!)
/usr/lib        # for package manger installed apps 
/usr/local/lib  # for user installed apps
```

There are many others, but you should most likely stay with `/usr/local/lib`.
Next you need to tell your system where to find these libraries. The cool system dude (who knows what he is doing) way to do this is using `ldconfig`, however, you may do stuff you regret, if you make a mistake here. The safest way to use that command is by using the flags `-v -n` to make the command verbose and to **specify** what library directory you need to add.

```
sudo ldconfig -v -n /usr/local/lib/your-uber-libs
```

Done. But if you only wanna test something, then rather use your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` directly from command line, like this:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/your-uber-libs ./your_uber_command
```

Alternatively, add the following to your `.bashrc` script.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib/your-uber-libs
```

Now you can run your dynamically linked command.

Comment: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:<your_lib_path>` helped me fix it

Answer (score 2):

Try installing the library **libxerces-c3.1 as**. Use the command mentioned below to install the library.

```
 sudo apt-get install libxerces-c3.1
```

This worked like a charm for me.