# Error while loading shared libraries: libnetcdf.so.7

Tags: fortran, codeblocks, netcdf

I have installed netcdf fortran successfully. I have a program that calls the netcdf module, and I was able to compile (build) it on Code::Blocks without any warning and error. But, when I run the program  I got an error message saying that **'Error while loading shared libraries: libnetcdf.so.7'**. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: You need to provide much more details about your system configuration. See [ask] and [mcve]. Especially you need to show your paths to the libraries and the relevant environment variables like `LD_LIBRARAY_PATH`.

Comment: Potential duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480764/linux-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-s/28460293 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514997/error-loading-shared-libraries?noredirect=1&lq=1 Please read it carefully. Try exporting the path to the library in `LD_LIBRARAY_PATH`.

Comment: Thanks for your  suggestions. I had exported the path to the library  in LD_LIBRARAY_PATH. Now I found the solution, and the problem was me not letting code::blocks link to the library.

Answer (score 0):

Now I found the solution, and the problem was me not letting code::blocks link to the library. I first exported the path to the library in LD_LIBRARAY_PATH. Then I followed the following step to add the library to code::block run time. Project----build option------linker-------add [the directory where the netcdf library is installed]

Comment: Good that you found a solution but it would be good to share how you solved your problem.

Comment: Sure I can do that.  I first exported  the path to the library in LD_LIBRARAY_PATH. Then I followed the following step to add the library to code::block run time. Project----build option------linker-------add [the directory where the netcdf library is installed].

Comment: Please add this information in your answer, not in a comment.