# re2 library loading

Tags: c++, regex, re2

I am using the following code to test google's RE2 library

```
int main()
{
  int r = RE2::FullMatch("hello", "h.*o");
  cout <<" match = " << r << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I am compling using the following command -

```
g++ -lre2 -o retest retest.cc
```

It is compiling fine, but when I am trying to run retest with ./retest its throwing the following error -

```
error while loading shared libraries: libre2.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have  checked and libre2.so.0 library does exist at user/local/lib directory and re2/obj/so directory. So why is this error coming am I forgetting some detail to add ?

Comment: Could this be a solution? http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/32861. Just set your LD_LIBRARY_PATH to point to lib directory where libre.so.0 is located.

Comment: where is the libre2.so.0 file located? is it in your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and/or a path from /etc/ld.so.conf? did you run ldconfig after installing it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linux error while loading shared libraries: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480764/linux-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-s)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Running `sudo ldconfig` did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Classic pitfall:

```
g++ -o retest retest.cc -lre2
```

The libraries should be last

**Edit** to be honest I'm surprised at the absence of link errors. I'll keep it around in case you missed some information in the question

Comment: Probably it's time to make sure the library is in the ld's path and rerun ldconfig.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker: +1 possibly. Allthough on most systems `usr/local/lib` is in the ldconfig and libre2 is packaged

Comment: I think yes, skipping path check is most likely safe and in case the library was installed from source `ldconfig` may be of help.