# lib-xerces not found

Tags: c++, xml, g++, xerces

I'm using xerces(http://xerces.apache.org) lib to parse a XML file in C++, so I downloaded the source code, ran a ./configure, make, make install, so when I execute
g++ -o parser parser.cpp
and I execute ./parser, I get:
./parser: error while loading shared libraries: libxerces-c-3.1.so: cannot open shared object file. No such file or directory.

When I search into /usr/lib or /lib I can't find where libxerces-c-3.1.so did go, nor where libxerces-c-3.1.so is. Does someone know how could I solve that problem?

Comment: But if it was not present, how did it link against it in the first place during the compilation step?

Comment: It linked correctly. I ran
g++ -o parser parser.cpp -lxerces-c
compiled flawlessly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try running ldconfig command? 
[ldconfig examples](http://linux.101hacks.com/unix/ldconfig/)
The only thing that I can think of is some issue with symbolic links, if it has crossed linking successfully.

Related question :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480764/linux-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-s