# node: error while loading shared libraries: libv8.so.3

Tags: linux, node.js

I'm encountering an error after installing node on a new machine.

```
$ -node
node: error while loading shared libraries: libv8.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried to install v8 with the instructions from http://code.google.com/p/v8/wiki/BuildingWithGYP

but with very little luck. Any help on this issue?

My system is:

> SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64) VERSION = 11 PATCHLEVEL = 2

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why do you think that the error message is lying?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I don't think it is lying? I am just having trouble installing the dependency that is v8

Comment: Then perhaps you should go back to "This is how I installed V8. What did I do wrong?".

Answer (score 1):

I had encountered the same problem, and that answer solved it -
[Linux error while loading shared libraries: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480764/linux-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-s?rq=1)

long story short ,

```
$ locate libv8.so.3
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/my_library/path.so.something
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
$ ./my_app
```

GL,
ido

Answer (score 1):

The Node RPM you installed has a dependency on the `libv8.so.3` module from the v8 RPM. Install v8, then search for the module and copy it to the path where node is searching for modules. Edit the `~/.bash_profile` with the paths of v8's enable file to correctly map v8 on the machine.

```
$find / -name libv8.so*
$cp /the found path/libv8.so /node module path/
$find / -name enable | grep v8*
$vim /path to v8 enable file/enable (highlight the export PATH statements)
$vim ~/.bash_profile
Shift+I (paste in the contents of the v8 enable file)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using scl to load libs and encountered a similar problem. ended up starting my rails server after a deploy via:

```
# stop
pid=$(lsof -i tcp:3000 -t)
[ -z "$pid" ] || kill $pid

# start
scl enable rh-ror41 nodejs010 rh-ruby22 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/rh/rh-ruby22/root/usr/lib64/:/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib:/opt/rh/nodejs010/root/lib64 &
                                         bundle install &
                                         rails server -d -b 0.0.0.0'
```