# how to compile with liblbfgs?

Tags: c++, g++

I downloaded liblbfgs from [here](http://www.chokkan.org/software/liblbfgs/)  and compiled the sample code from its document with

```
g++ sample.cpp -o sample -llbfgs
```

Then I run

```
./sample
```

But it says

```
./sample: error while loading shared libraries: 
liblbfgs-1.10.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Are there any extra flags that I have to add? Thanks!!

Comment: add library path -L"librarypath" and include path -I"includepath".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for similar problem is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480764/linux-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-s). You may have to do `ldconfig`, as you have recently installed a shared library.