# libboost_python-py27.so.1.53.o No such file or directory

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, shared-libraries

I have one `.so library` compiled for `x86` and I need to deploy and use on another computer(laso Ubuntu), but when I start I get error `libboost_python-py27.so.1.53.o No such file or directory`, when I ls through /usr/lib I found `libboost_python-py27.so.1.49.o` . What to do ?

Comment: In my case, I installed boost in a custom path, so the solution was to call `ldconfig` as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480764/linux-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-s)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numbers indicate the version of boost. (See [boost.org](http://boost.org))
Your code is looking for 1.53, but you only have 1.49 deployed.

You will need to get a copy of the newer libraries and deploy them - for example by getting the relevant version of boost and building the libraries. Or copying them from the machine which has the newer libraries.

Comment: I put ln -s /usr/lib/libboost_python-py27.so.1.49.0 /usr/lib/libboost_python-27.so.1.53.0 and it works

Comment: It might fail horribly in strange ways at runtime depending on which features changed between the versions. Or you may get lucky and the python bindings haven't changed, but this is asking for trouble!