# libcurl, cpuminer installation without root permissions

Tags: linux, root, libcurl, bitcoin

I would like to run Cpuminer on Debian 6 (i686-pc-linux-gnu) without root permissions.
I downloaded this software:

```
http://sourceforge.net/projects/cpuminer/files/pooler-cpuminer-2.3.2.tar.gz/download
```

And i do:

in /home/user/download

```
tar -xvf pooler-cpuminer-2.3.2.tar.gz
cd cpuminer-2.3.2
./configure --prefix=$HOME
```

and I get error:

```
...
checking for pthread_create in -lpthread... yes
checking for gawk... (cached) mawk
checking for curl-config... no
checking whether libcurl is usable... no
configure: error: Missing required libcurl >= 7.15.2
```

So I downloaded source archives

```
http://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.34.0.tar.gz
```

and I do

in /home/user/download

```
tar -xvf curl-7.34.0.tar.gz
cd curl-7.34.0
./configure --prefix=$HOME
make
make install
```

It seems that everything is OK, but...

in /home/user/bin
    ( curl  curl-config  minerd )

I try run minerd and I get error!

```
./minerd
./minerd: error while loading shared libraries: libcurl.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I try in /home/user/lib
rename libcurl.so.4.3.0 to libcurl.so.4, but still error exist.

```
    ldd minerd

    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb7732000)
    libcurl.so.4 => not found
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i686/cmov/libpthread.so.0 (0xb7710000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i686/cmov/libc.so.6 (0xb75c8000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb7733000)
```

Please help me.
Maybe someone else has a another way of mining for example Bitcoins on Linux without root rights?

Comment: Build static libcurl, link against it -> problem solved.

Comment: You might want to take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480764/linux-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try : 
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev -y

And after :

./configure CFLAGS="-O3"

make

Bye

Comment: Tried so many different things until I found this.  It was the first command that worked.  Related to Nicehash and sgminer installation.

Comment: Happy to have helped you ;)

Comment: "without root permissions"