# error while loading shared libraries: libgsl.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, gsl

I use gsl.
After I compiled my .cpp file and run it, I faced with below error:

error while loading shared libraries: libgsl.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I found same as this problem in:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cortex_var/6vluX7pP0Sk
&
[Linux error while loading shared libraries: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480764/linux-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-s?answertab=votes#tab-top)
&
http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Shared-Libraries.html

And I have done as in the above links wrote but the error is still remained.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Where is libgsl.so.0 located?

Comment: It is located at right place I reinstalled gsl from terminal and above error is not exist now. But I have segmentation fault and should come over it. Thanks any way

Comment: Thank you for your link provided. I found https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Shared-Libraries.html is useful to me. Have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 16):

First, you need to locate the file (libgsl.so.0). You can do this, for example, by using the `find` command:

```
sudo find / -name "libgsl.so.0"
```

Let us assume, the file is located in `/usr/local/lib`.
(If the file has not been found, install the corresponding package *or* download the source, build it and install it.)
Now, you have two options:

(1) Quick & Dirty:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

This adds the path of the library to an environment variable. The disadvantage of this option is, that it is only valid for the current session. It will not work for other users. It will not work once you log off and on again.

(2) Permanent:

Review your `/etc/ld.so.conf`. If `/usr/local/lib` is not listed there, add it. Now, run `ldconfig` to detect the shared object file and add it to some system-wide index.

Answer (score 15):

To make it work do the following steps

Start Borne Shell

```
$LD_LIBRARY_PATH= path to your gsl lib folder inside the gsl installation folder
$export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

now run your executable

It should work fine.

Answer (score 7):

In my experience, **fastStructure** depends on **gsl 1.6** but not the latest version.

```
wget http://gnu.mirror.vexxhost.com/gsl/gsl-1.6.tar.gz
tar -zxvf gsl-1.6.tar.gz
cd gsl-1.16
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Add these lines to your `.bashrc` file on your home directory.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib
export CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include"
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib"
```

then, run source ~/.bashrc to set these environment variables.

It works fine when I change the version from the latest to the 1.6.

Answer (score 6):

I got the same error with Krita on Arch Linux. I made a symlink with

```
ln /usr/lib/libgsl.so /usr/lib/libgsl.so.0
```

and that fixed it.

Comment: In my case "libgsl.so" was in "/usr/local/lib" so "ln /usr/local/lib/libgsl.so /usr/local/lib/libgsl.so.0" solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/shg047/software/gsl/lib/
```

such as: to-mr: error while loading shared libraries: libgsl.so.19: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried updating your library? The program I was trying to run simply needed a newer version of gsl (I had 1.9.5 while it needed 2.0.0 or newer).

If you are on arch you can run:

```
yaourt gsl
```

and select the appropriate one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `gsl-config --libs` in you makefile or in the command line when you link the gsl library. Just type `gsl-config` you can find the options it offers to you. Choose the options you need, you will find compile and link process much easier than before. As a result, when I type `gsl-config --libs` in my terminal, I get `-L/usr/local/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm`. Although it is very simple, first you should know where you gsl is installed. You can add the directory to the `PATH` environment variable or use the absolute path to execute `gsl-config` .

Answer (score 0):

I needed `libgsl.so.19`:

`/snap/inkscape/current/bin/inkscape: error while loading shared libraries: libgsl.so.19: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I solved it with:

1. Installing [Anaconda](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/install/linux.html)
2. searched for `libgsl.so.19` and found it in ~/anaconda3/lib
3. run `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:~/anaconda3/lib` (best [add it to ~/.basrc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37478901/6747994))

Comment: It's fine to do this, but a better permanent solution is to install your library ( or a symlink to it ) in `/usr/local/lib`, and then make sure `/etc/ld.so.cache` has updated by running `ldconfig` or `sudo ldconfig`, depending on the permissions in the `/etc` directory. This saves you from having to add a bunch of directories from your home directory to LD_LIBRARY_PATH in a login script, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The solution by Max Ghenis and ManuelAtWork helped me with a related issue with a different shared library. I wanted to document my steps here in case it helps somebody else.

**TL;DR**

Even if `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` contains `/usr/local/lib`, and your shared object library ( the `.so` file ) is located there, you still might get an error like

`error while loading shared libraries: <INSERT LIBRARY NAME>.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

If your linker cache `/etc/ld.so.cache` has not been rebuilt since the library was installed.

You can fix this by running `ldconfig` ( or `sudo ldconfig`, depending on the `/etc` directory permissions, which are likely only writeable by the root user ).

When successful, `ldconfig` prints no output. For more detailed output when running `ldconfig`, use the `-v` ( or `--verbose` ) flag.

If you have ever run into this error, and then it magically fixed itself while you were troubleshooting, it's probably because you followed someone's advice and did something like

`ldconfig -v | grep <INSERT LIBRARY NAME>`

to make sure the `.so` file was in a directory listed in LD_LIBRARY_PATH, like `/usr/local/lib`. It's a reasonable troubleshooting step to perform if you already confirmed that directory is included in `/etc/ld.so.conf` or `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf`, but `ldconfig -v` still *runs* `ldconfig` in verbose mode, which rebuilds `/etc/ld.so.cache`, and probably fixed your issue.

If your error mysteriously fixed itself after some time without you having to run `ldconfig`, then something else on your system must have run it since then - e.g. a startup script, a scheduled task, or installation scripts for other software.

**Details**

I recently installed `libhttpserver`, following the instructions on its GitHub repo, which follow the standard steps with the `make` command. I was able to compile an external program against the library, but when I ran my program I received the same error related to dynamic linkage.

```
$ g++ -o server server.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs libhttpserver`
./server
```

`error while loading shared libraries: libhttpserver.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I confirmed `pkg-config` knew linker flags and library names, meaning the `.pc` file(s) for `libhttpserver` had been installed correctly.

```
$ pkg-config --cflags --libs libhttpserver
-I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/httpserver -I/usr/include/p11-kit-1 -L/usr/local/lib -lhttpserver -lmicrohttpd
```

I noted the `-L/usr/local/lib` flag, and confirmed the shared object files were located there.

```
$ find /usr/local/lib -name '*httpserver*'
/usr/local/lib/libhttpserver.so.0
/usr/local/lib/libhttpserver.la
/usr/local/lib/libhttpserver.so.0.19.0
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libhttpserver.pc
/usr/local/lib/libhttpserver.a
/usr/local/lib/libhttpserver.so
```

Following a suggestion from this thread, I searched for the library name in the output of `ldconfig -v`

```
$ ldconfig -v |grep libhttpserver
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
(from /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu.conf:4 and /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu.conf:3)
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/lib32' given more than once
(from /etc/ld.so.conf.d/zz_i386-biarch-compat.conf:3 and /etc/ld.so.conf.d/zz_i386-biarch-compat.conf:2)
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/libx32' given more than once
(from /etc/ld.so.conf.d/zz_x32-biarch-compat.conf:3 and /etc/ld.so.conf.d/zz_x32-biarch-compat.conf:2)
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
(from <builtin>:0 and /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu.conf:3)
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
(from <builtin>:0 and /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu.conf:3)
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/lib' given more than once
(from <builtin>:0 and <builtin>:0)
    libhttpserver.so.0 -> libhttpserver.so.0.19.0
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 is the dynamic linker, ignoring

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /lib32/ld-linux.so.2 is the dynamic linker, ignoring

/sbin/ldconfig.real: Can't create temporary cache file /etc/ld.so.cache~: Permission denied
```

I noticed the error message at the end of the output

`/sbin/ldconfig.real: Can't create temporary cache file /etc/ld.so.cache~: Permission denied`

I decided to read the man page for `ldconfig` to learn more about what `ldconfig -v` was doing.

`ldconfig creates the necessary links and cache to the most recent shared libraries found in the di‐rectories specified on the command line, in the file /etc/ld.so.conf, and in the  trusted directories, /lib and /usr/lib`

```
       -v, --verbose
              Verbose mode.  Print current version number, the name of each directory as it is scanned, and
              any links that are created.  Overrides quiet mode.
```

Since `ldconfig -v` flag was doing the same thing as `ldconfig`, but just with more detailed output, I decided to run `ldconfig` without it.

```
$ ldconfig
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Can't create temporary cache file /etc/ld.so.cache~: Permission denied
```

This time the error message from before was the only output. Before resorting to using `sudo`, I wanted to learn more about what was happening. Since `ldconfig` was trying to create a file called `/etc/ld.so.cache~`, I decided to look for that file or files with similar names.

```
$ find /etc -name 'ld.so*'
/etc/ld.so.cache
find: ‘/etc/ssl/private’: Permission denied
find: ‘/etc/softhsm’: Permission denied
/etc/ld.so.conf.d
find: ‘/etc/polkit-1/localauthority’: Permission denied
find: ‘/etc/cups/ssl’: Permission denied
/etc/ld.so.conf
```

I figured `/etc/ld.so.cache` must be the cache the `ldconfig` man page was talking about. I decided to look for my library name there.

`$ grep libhttpserver /etc/ld.so.cache`

But `grep` returned no matches. Instead I looked for `/usr/local/lib`.

```
$ grep /usr/local/lib /etc/ld.so.cache
grep: /etc/ld.so.cache: binary file matches
```

That found a match. Reading the man pages for `ldconfig`, I learned the `-p` flag prints the cache, which is a binary file, in a human readable format, so I searched for `/usr/local/lib` in the output of `ldconfig -p`.

`ldconfig -p | grep /usr/local/lib`

I found matches for other libraries in `/usr/local/lib` (e.g. libwayland, but not `libhttpserver`.

```
    libwayland-server.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-server.so.0
    libwayland-server.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-server.so
    libwayland-egl.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1
    libwayland-egl.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so
    libwayland-cursor.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-cursor.so.0
    libwayland-cursor.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-cursor.so
    libwayland-client.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-client.so.0
    libwayland-client.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-client.so

...
```

Clearly the linker `ld.so` had at one point been able to find libraries located in `/usr/local/lib`, because they were in the linker's cache. I confirmed this was still the case by checking `/etc/ld.so.conf` and `/etc/ld.so.conf.d`.

`$ cat /etc/ld.so.conf`

`include /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf`

`$ grep -x /usr/local/lib /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf`

`/etc/ld.so.conf.d/libc.conf:/usr/local/lib`

I was curious what was normally responsible for running `ldconfig` on my system, but I couldn't find a systemd service, crontab, or init.d script responsible for running it. I had built libraries from source before that were installed to `/usr/local/lib`, but I never had this issue.

I finally did find a reference to `ldconfig` in a build script in the source code for one such library I had installed a while ago. I concluded it was up to the author of the source code whether or not to run `ldconfig` after installation, and that whether or not the system runs `ldconfig` automatically on startup, etc., depends on what Linux distribution you're using.

Having convinced myself I wasn't doing any harm by rebuilding the linker cache, I finally resorted to running `ldconfig` as root.

`sudo ldconfig`

This time, there was no error message about failing to create a temporary cache file. Before attempting to run my code again, I confirmed the linker cache now contained a reference to `libhttpserver`.

```
$ ldconfig -p|grep libhttpserver
    libhttpserver.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libhttpserver.so.0
    libhttpserver.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libhttpserver.so
```

Finally, I tried to run program again and was successful.

`$ ./server`

Note that I didn't need to recompile my program after running `sudo ldconfig`, since it already contained references to the correct shared library. The issue was just that the linker cache `/etc/ld.so.cache` needed to be updated by running `sudo ldconfig` after installing `libhttpserver`.

When you build libraries from source, you may run into this issue, depending on whether or not the source maintainers choose to include that step in their installation scripts.