# Can't find shared library running freshly-built nginx

Tags: c, linux, nginx, shared

I've built nginx on my target machine (Linux) with a 3rd party module (ngx_mongo).
This module required two additional libraries to be present: pcre and yajl.
I built and installed these two separately and they installed to /usr/local/lib and headers to /usr/local/include.

I then configured nginx's build:  configure --add-module=/home/greg.zoller/working/ngx_mongo
This found all the needed libs and successfully built w/o errors.
Installed nginx to default /usr/local/nginx.

When I go to run /usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx I get this error:

./nginx: error while loading shared libraries: libyajl.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Why can't it find libyajl.so.2?  This file exists in /usr/local/lib and the build found it.

I ran ldconfig -v and the yajl library was not there.  I tried running (as root and not) just ldconfig.  No change.

What am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linux error while loading shared libraries: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480764/linux-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-s)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dynamic loader only looks for libs present in folders declared in `/etc/ld.so.conf`. `/usr/local/lib` may not be there by default. Also when a new lib is added, you need to run `ldconfig` since the contents of lib folders are cached.

Comment: Thanks for 'ldconfig' cache note. just saved my day.