# error while loading shared libraries libpng16

Tags: c, shared-libraries, libpng

I am trying to compile and run this [code](http://zarb.org/~gc/html/libpng.html) under ubuntu 14.04. I downloaded and installed [libpng](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html) version 1.6.12. I am able to compile the code using `gcc test.c -lpng` but when I try to run it, I get this error: 

`./a.out: error while loading shared libraries: libpng16.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

**edit:** 
So I found libpng16.so.16, it was in `/usr/local/lib` and I copied it to `/usr/local/include/libpng16/` and as well to `/usr/local/include/` and recompiled the code, anyway the problem still persists.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can download the library from the link
https://sourceforge.net/projects/libpng/?source=directory

It will download a file something like "libpng-1.6.32.tar.xz"

Simply extract the file go inside folder and run these commands to install

```
./configure
make check
make install
```

Then you need to run after installing any library

```
ldconfig
```

Comment: I had to use `sudo make install` and `sudo ldconfig` instead for those last 2 commands.

Answer (score 33):

Ok so I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480764/linux-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-s?rq=1). The trick is to run `sudo ldconfig` after you install some shared library.

Comment: I thought it would be harder, but this worked perfectly! +1

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem before I had installed it form below link and problem fixed.

I hope yours would be fixed as well

[PNG reference library: libpng](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libpng/files/libpng16/)

Comment: Thanks for answer, unfortunately it didn't help in my case.