# Installing xml2 in R in Fedora 27

Tags: r, fedora, libxml2, xml2

I'm having trouble installing xml2 in RStudio, running Fedora 27. On running `install.packages('xml2')`, I get the following error:

```
installing to /home/ryi/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/xml2/libs
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
Error : /tmp/Rtmp2sKZQZ/R.INSTALL689b37bd918d/xml2/man/read_xml.Rd:47: unable to load shared object '/home/ryi/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/xml2/libs/xml2.so':
  libicui18n.so.58: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
ERROR: installing Rd objects failed for package ‘xml2’
* removing ‘/home/ryi/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/xml2’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘xml2’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpPs5Gzi/downloaded_packages’
```

I noticed in my `/usr/lib64/`, I have `libicui18n.so.57` only, so I tried copying a `libicui18n.so.58` there, and I got the following error:

```
installing to /home/ryi/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/xml2/libs
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
Error : /tmp/Rtmp908Ecf/R.INSTALL653812e0e41f/xml2/man/read_xml.Rd:47: unable to load shared object '/home/ryi/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/xml2/libs/xml2.so':
  libicuuc.so.58: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
ERROR: installing Rd objects failed for package ‘xml2’
* removing ‘/home/ryi/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/xml2’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘xml2’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpPs5Gzi/downloaded_packages’
```

And I noticed the same problem -- I have version .57, not version .58 of this library as well. Before I repeat this over and over, is this in fact a shared library problem? Or, is there a way to fix this all at once?

I have xml2 installed (`libxml2-devel-2.9.5-2.fc27.x86_64`) already.

Comment: It could be a permissions issue. Do not install via RStudio but run the install at command line with R.exe using `sudo`.

Answer (score 3):

Since no one answered this yet and I've found a hacky solution, I thought I'd give an update on what worked.

It appears that my issue was that, even upon installing libxml2-devel, the version of the libraries I had in `/usr/lib64` were not the same version required by RStudio's xml2 package. For example, regarding the particular package being mentioned in my question above, `libicuuc.so.58`, only `libicuuc.so.57` could be found in `/usr/lib64`.

Running `locate libicuuc.so.58`, I found that anaconda3 has the correct versions of the libraries, so I got around the above problem temporarily by simply adding `~/anaconda3/lib` to `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, roughly following [instructions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480764/linux-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-s).

This is a bit hacky, but led to successful installation.

*Edit **(IMPORTANT)**:* Adding `~/anaconda3/lib` to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in `.bashrc` caused a login loop, presumably because Fedora was trying to use the wrong libraries. To fix this, I added the lines:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/ryi/anaconda3/lib/
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

to `R_HOME/etc/ldpaths`.

Comment: Installing `libxml2-devel` works for me on Fedora 30.

Answer (score -1):

I have solved this problem by install the ICU4C by source:

1. downloading ICU4C 58.2 from: [ICU-Project](http://site.icu-project.org/download)
2. compiled
3. added the library location to `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`,

the install will be work.