# GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugins while they are existent

Tags: gstreamer, wayland

I am porting wayland KMS protocol to communication between waylandsink 1.12.2 and weston 2.0. I am getting stuck at loading some libraries.
They do exist in our system, but the errors still generated during run-time execution.

```
(gst-plugin-scanner:1694): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstrsvg.so': librsvg-2.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

(gst-plugin-scanner:1694): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstsdpelem.so': libgstsdp-1.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

(gst-plugin-scanner:1694): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstuvch264.so': libgstapp-1.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

(gst-plugin-scanner:1694): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstneonhttpsrc.so': libneon.so.27: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

(gst-plugin-scanner:1694): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstsbc.so': libsbc.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

(gst-plugin-scanner:1694): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgsthls.so': libgstapp-1.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

(gst-plugin-scanner:1694): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstvulkan.so': libvulkan.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

(gst-plugin-scanner:1694): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstcamerabin.so': libgstapp-1.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

(gst-plugin-scanner:1694): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstdashdemux.so': libgstapp-1.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

(gst-plugin-scanner:1694): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstaudiovisualizers.so': libgstfft-1.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

(gst-plugin-scanner:1694): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstwebp.so': libwebp.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

(gst-plugin-scanner:1694): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstsmoothstreaming.so': libgstapp-1.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

-

root@machine:~# ls /usr/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstrsvg.so
/usr/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstrsvg.so
```

Anyone can explain this ? Thanks in advance.

Edit: It seemed that the problem came from broken symbolic links

```
# ldconfig
ldconfig: /usr/lib/libgstwayland-1.0.so.0 is not a symbolic link

ldconfig: /usr/lib/libgsturidownloader-1.0.so.0 is not a symbolic link

ldconfig: /usr/lib/libgstbadbase-1.0.so.0 is not a symbolic link

ldconfig: /usr/lib/libgstbadvideo-1.0.so.0 is not a symbolic link

ldconfig: /usr/lib/libgstphotography-1.0.so.0 is not a symbolic link

ldconfig: /usr/lib/libgstinsertbin-1.0.so.0 is not a symbolic link

ldconfig: /usr/lib/libgstmpegts-1.0.so.0 is not a symbolic link

ldconfig: /usr/lib/libgstplayer-1.0.so.0 is not a symbolic link

ldconfig: /usr/lib/libgstbadaudio-1.0.so.0 is not a symbolic link

ldconfig: /usr/lib/libgstbasecamerabinsrc-1.0.so.0 is not a symbolic link

ldconfig: /usr/lib/libgstadaptivedemux-1.0.so.0 is not a symbolic link
```

I tried to rebuild the system. Everything worked ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest the following ways to resolve this:

1. You might have to re-configure and rebuild the libraries with the sources.
2. Or do `apt-get install` for any packages that resolves this library
3. The symlinks to these libraries might be mixed up due to the version numbers.

Also try reading [this](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html). Better answer over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480764/linux-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-s).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem came from broken symlinks.