# ImportError: liblapack.so.3gf: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: numpy

I have both python 2.7.16 and python 3.5.2 installed on my ubuntu 16.04 LTS and numpy used to work well on both of them but recently something went wrong with numpy on python 2 while it still running smoothly on python 3

I have tried to uninstall and install the numpy package and this did not fix anything

The exact stdout I am getting is as follow:

```
python -c "import numpy as np"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ahmed/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 153, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/home/ahmed/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/home/ahmed/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .polynomial import *
  File "/home/ahmed/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/polynomial.py", line 19, in <module>
    from numpy.linalg import eigvals, lstsq, inv
  File "/home/ahmed/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from .linalg import *
  File "/home/ahmed/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 29, in <module>
    from numpy.linalg import lapack_lite, _umath_linalg
ImportError: liblapack.so.3gf: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Have a look at this `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480764/linux-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-s`  .. Maybe it could help.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed [Linux error while loading shared libraries: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480764/linux-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-s) resolved the problem. I had have only to do the following:

```
sudo find / -iname liblapack.so.3gf
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:*path_to_lib_as_found*
sudo ldconfig -v
```

Thanks to Abdur Rehman for the hint

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Does your Ubuntu have the latest lapack library? Try installing `sudo apt install liblapack3gf liblapack-dev`. Sometimes you need to run `sudo ldconfig` after the install.