# Integrating shared object in an application, ldd and readelf show different outputs

Tags: c++, opencv, shared-objects, ldd, readelf

I am trying to integrate OpenCV into an application and facing some issues below.

```
error while loading shared libraries: libopencv_imgproc.so.4.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

However, when I check the output of *ldd* and *readelf*, below are the differences.

```
$readelf -d <app name>
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.1]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libopencv_core.so.4.1]

$ldd <app name>
libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.1 => <path to opencv>/opencv/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.1 (0x00007f04555b2000)
libopencv_imgproc.so.4.1 => <path to opencv>/opencv/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.4.1 (0x00007f0453e8f000)
libopencv_core.so.4.1 => <path to opencv>/opencv/lib/libopencv_core.so.4.1 (0x00007f0452774000)
```

As shown above, *libopencv_imgproc* is missing from *readelf* output. Can someone point out what causes such behavior?

Comment: Maybe check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480764/linux-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-s) out. Seems relevant to your issue.

Comment: Not really. I have checked full names and symlinks are already there.

Comment: Ur library directory added to /etc/ld.so.conf.d/opencv.conf ? In my side I also tried readelf and gave me also ".....(NEEDED)." But this didnt create a problem to integrate OpenCV to my app. I think problem is not about readelf.

Comment: Just guessing: Is imgproc a dependency introduced by imgcodecs , and ldd follows that, while readelf only lists first level dependencies?