# Why application stopped to find library if it already exists

Tags: linux, asp.net-mvc, debian, shared-libraries, wkhtmltopdf

Mono ASP.NET MVC 4.8 application uses wkhtmltopdf to create pdf file in Debian Linux.

wkhtmltopdf suddenly stopped working. Running it from shell throws library not found error:

```
root@x:/usr/local/bin# ./wkhtmltopdf
./wkhtmltopdf: error while loading shared libraries: libQt5Core.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Symlink of library exists in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu :

```
root@x:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu# ls -l libQt5Core.so.5* 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      20 jaan  30  2020 libQt5Core.so.5 ->
 libQt5Core.so.5.11.3 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      20 jaan  30  2020
libQt5Core.so.5.11 -> libQt5Core.so.5.11.3
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5200168 jaan  30  2020 libQt5Core.so.5.11.3
```

How to allow wkhtmltopdf to find library in Debian Linux ?

I tried to copy library to the same directory where whhtmltopdf exists (/usr/local/bin ) but problem persists.
It has worked for years but suddenly stopped working. Debian VPS server was re-booted unexpectedly, maybe this caused it.

Ran ldcongfig according to

[Linux error while loading shared libraries: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480764/linux-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-s)

and tried

```
apt reinstall wkhtmltopdf
chmod 0777 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5.11.3
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
ldconfig
ldconfig -v | grep libQt5Core.so.5
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
./wkhtmltopdf
```

but problem persists.

ldd returns:

```
:/usr/local/bin# ldd ./wkhtmltopdf
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffff53a3000)
        libjpeg.so.62 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.62 (0x00007ff7d2c8f000)
        libpng16.so.16 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16 (0x00007ff7d2c56000)
        libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1 (0x00007ff7d2a4c000)
        libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007ff7d2a06000)
        libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007ff7d294a000)
        libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007ff7d2738000)
        libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007ff7d25f5000)
        libssl.so.1.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1 (0x00007ff7d2563000)
        libcrypto.so.1.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007ff7d227a000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007ff7d205c000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007ff7d2057000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007ff7d204d000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007ff7d202a000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007ff7d1ea6000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007ff7d1d23000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007ff7d1d09000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007ff7d1b48000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ff7d5c28000)
        libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007ff7d1b0b000)
        libuuid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007ff7d1b00000)
        libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007ff7d1ad6000)
        libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007ff7d18d2000)
        libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007ff7d16cc000)
        libbsd.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0x00007ff7d16b2000)
```

Comment: What does `ldd ./wkhtmltopdf` show ?

Comment: I updated question with its output

Comment: Can you run `ldd` on each .so to see who is using libQt5Core.so.5 ?