# cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory | including libbpf with userspace program

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries, ebpf

So in my userspace program I am calling some functions like `bpf_object__open_file` which are part of `libbpf` library installed with `PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/build/root/lib64/pkgconfig DESTDIR=/build/root make install`

So when I compile the it compiles just fine, no error with this command

```
  clang -L /build/root/usr/lib64/ -I /usr/include/ -Wall -o user u.c -lbpf
```

so these files exists in my /build/root/usr/lib64 directory

```
    libbpf.a  libbpf.so  libbpf.so.0  libbpf.so.0.7.0  pkgconfig
```

But when I run the program like

```
 sudo ./user
```

It throws message that

```
 ./user: error while loading shared libraries: libbpf.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So basically I am creating shared library, giving the path but why running the program not able to find my `libbpf.so.0` shared library

can anyone tell why is that the case I am getting message can't find library

As Qeole mentioned in comment

So I did this

root@/dir/# ldd ./user

and it gives me this output without any location where did it tried to find path directory

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffcd77e7000)
libbpf.so.0 => not found
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f9b3943c000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f9b39642000)
```

Comment: Did you see this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480764/linux-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-s

Comment: `ldd ./user` should also tell you where the system expects to find the libraries, I believe.

Comment: @Qeole I tried ldd command it gives me this `libbpf.so.0 => not found`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the libbpf library directory to your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable.

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/build/root/usr/lib64
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Then go ahead an run the program. Note that if you run it with sudo, you may also need to set root's `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

```
$ sudo su
# LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/build/root/usr/lib64
# export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
# ./user
```

You can verify that libbfp was found with the same ldd command.

Comment: ok thanks it worked but now I am getting error  `root@fawad-HP-Pavilion-dm4-Notebook-PC:/home/fawad/Desktop# ./user
libbpf: elf: c.o is not a valid eBPF object file
ERROR: opening BPF object file failed
root@f`

Comment: do u know how to make clang find arch asm/types.h. I think I had to use -I or something like `clang -arch` but the later one throwing tons of error and the earlier one not finding it

Comment: `clang -I /path/to/asm/types.h` should include the file for you. as far as your other error, it seems the program does not recognize file c.o as valid eEBF file. you might need to find the correct input file.