# How to preload library with ld_preload to wine(windows game)?

Tags: c, hook, ld, wine, ld-preload

I want to learn how to preload and hook functions in wine running windows apps.
I'm trying to preload a library with `ld_preload` to wine(windows game(32-bit)) on Arch Linux (64-bit but I think I installed 32-bit support). I get the error `wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32` and the same for `ELFCLASS64`.

Full error text:

> "ERROR: ld.so: object './eve.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded
> (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored."

the same for 64bit and another one

> ERROR: ld.so: object './eve.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded
> (cannot open shared object file): ignored.

How am I getting "wrong class" when I have both 32 and 64-bit installed? What architecture do I need to make it work right?

Wow.exe:

> Wow.exe: PE32 executable (GUI) Intel 80386, for MS Windows

I tried to build with and without the `-m32` flag ( I changed all `uint32` to `uint64`):

```
gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Werror -m32 -O0 -fpic -shared -ldl -lGL -o eve.so eve.c
```

I saw this answer:

> ltrace /lib/ld-linux.so.2 --preload /path/to/lib/strcmp.so ./exec

But don't know how to run it with wine running the app.

I want to learn how to preload and hook functions in wine running windows apps. I saw this guide:
https://www.ownedcore.com/forums/world-of-warcraft/world-of-warcraft-bots-programs/wow-memory-editing/276206-linux-simple-injection-ld_preload.html

Answer (score 1):

The `wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32` means you are trying to inject a 32-bit program into a 64-bit process. This would lead me to believe your game is 64-bit, and you should compile your libraries as 64-bit as well. But since you mention you saw the error for 64-bits as well, it would be best to check your wine installation directly. Run `pacman -Q --info wine` to check.

The second error message you reported, [`cannot open shared object file`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480764/linux-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-s), means the dynamic linker can't find your library. Double check all your file paths. Instead of using the relative import `./eve.so`, use a full absolute path (`/path/to/lib/eve.so`) so there's no ambiguity to the system. You usually want to specify an absolute path to LD_PRELOAD. The reason is that it being an environment variable, it's inherited by child processes - which may have a different working directory than the parent process. So any relative path would fail to locate the library to preload.

As for how to set the environment variable in Wine, `wine` passes on the entire shell environment variable space to the Windows environment variable space, so you just set the variable in Linux beforehand and it will be available to the game inside wine:

```
export LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/lib/eve.so
wine ...
```

As another note, `LD_PRELOAD` will affect the `wine` loader only. If you would like to affect `wineserver` as well:

```
wineserver -k
export LD_PRELOAD=...
wine ...
```

Finally, see [this post](https://www.ownedcore.com/forums/world-of-warcraft/world-of-warcraft-bots-programs/wow-memory-editing/330135-linux-ld_preload-injection-without-patching-wine.html) for more details if this still isn't working for you, it's a more in depth explanation of how to do injection into `wine` specifically.

Comment: I tried to build 64-bit and tried to run with 32-bit wine prefix and 64-bit. Always get error  (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32) and for 64-bit (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64). And thats strange...

Comment: Check your wine installation with `dpkg -l `. What do you see?

Comment: It's Arch linux : dpkg: commad not found. I will try to install Ubuntu on usb flash drive and try all this from there.

Comment: You can try just preload simple lib with one function to any app in wine. I tried and it didn't work even in Ubuntu. I got the same errors.

Comment: On arch linux you can see if an installed package is 32 or 64 bit by running "pacman -Q --info *package*".