# Eleveldb failed to load nif library

Tags: erlang, leveldb

I connected the library to the erlang project

Can't build library when building project

Tell me what could be the reason?

```
   =INFO REPORT==== 21-Aug-2023::13:08:13.424839 ===
    application: kernel
    exited: {{shutdown,
                 {failed_to_start_child,on_load,
                     {on_load_function_failed,eleveldb,
                         {error,
                             {load_failed,
                                 "Failed to load NIF library: '/opt/acq-work/_build/default/rel/dev/lib/eleveldb-riak_kv-3.0.12/priv/eleveldb.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'"}}}}},
             {kernel,start,[normal,[]]}}
    type: permanent
```

OS Centos7

Erlang/OTP 26

Rebar3 3.22.0

gcc (GCC) 11.2.1 20220127 (Red Hat 11.2.1-9)

cmake version 3.12.3

Updated gcc to version 11 did not help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linux error while loading shared libraries: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480764/linux-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-s)