# Link to libclang library successfully, but runtime error

Tags: clang, libclang

I have successfully linked to the libclang library and got the executable file, but there is a problem running the executable file.This is the makefile

```
a.exe:s.c
     clang $^ -o $@ -I/usr/local/llvm/include -L/usr/local/llvm/lib -lclang
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdQqH.png)

I tried to re-link libclang in the same directory as the source code, but still got an error

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Instead of linking to an image, please type out the error message in your post.

Comment: The error message says that the library cannot be found.  Have you checked that it exists?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linux error while loading shared libraries: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480764/linux-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-s)