php-intl not found on arch
How do I get php-intl working with arch?
$ composer update                      
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'intl' (tried: /usr/lib/php/modules/intl (/usr/lib/php/modules/intl: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/modules/intl.so (libicuio.so.75: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - codeigniter4/framework[v4.4.0, ..., v4.5.1] require ext-intl * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's intl extension.
    - Root composer.json requires codeigniter4/framework ^4.4 -> satisfiable by codeigniter4/framework[v4.4.0, ..., v4.5.1].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php/php.ini
    - /etc/php/conf.d/memcached.ini
You can also run `php --ini` in a terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
Alternatively, you can run Composer with `--ignore-platform-req=ext-intl` to temporarily ignore these required extensions.

I installed sudo pacman -S php-intl and enabled it in /etc/php/php.ini

Not sure if this is helpful or not: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28460293/231316
